# Does "world's largest" require a "the"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Consider the following phrases:

Example 1:

> CompanyX is **the** world's largest and leading authority for online dating.

Example 2:

> CompanyX is world's largest and leading authority for online dating.

As you can see, in the 2nd example the word "the" has been left out.
I am not sure if any of these sentences are wrong to say, or if there is a special exception or context when to leave out "the".

I have been looking on google for more information about this, but could not find clear anwsers about it.

I hope someone can clear this problem up for me, thank you in advance!

Comment: The general rule is that if the noun is somehow unique, the definite article is used. Ex.  _the_ moon, _the_ Atlantic Ocean, _the_ Himalayas, _the_ car (if it is the family vehicle) etc.

Comment: Similarly, do not forget the article on "leading" ... either "a" or "the" depending on whether it is the only "leading authority" or not.

Comment: "I have been looking on Google" is not evidence of research. The first port should be [grammar the "definite article"  superlative](https://www.google.com/search?ei=GiBpXJP5KMKXsAfWjYbABQ&q=grammar+the+%22definite+article%22+superlative&oq=grammar+the+%22definite+article%22+superlative&gs_l=psy-ab.3...32678.47141..47499...0.0..0.119.2188.5j16......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i30j0i8i30j0i22i30j0i13i30j0i8i13i30j33i10.M7CyjD2LpU0) *Then* you explain why these sites did not help you or if their explanations confused you.

Answer (score 1):

Here, *the* applies to *world*, not to *world's largest*.

> This is *the world's* largest bubble bath.

Consider the substitution of a local context instead of global:

> This is *our* largest fork.

Of course, *the* is not the only article that could help here, depending on the context and intention.

> In *a world's* largest city, there are usually districts.
>
> *My world's* largest gelatinous cube has 4,000 hit points.

Comment: Of course, everything goes out the window if this is "telegraphic" communication for a title or web page notation or some such.

Answer (score 1):

Except in titles, "the" should go before "world's largest". The same is true no matter the superlative used.

You can see this by searching [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (or another BYU corpus). The search I used was `* world 's largest`. About 95% of the matches were for "the world's largest", and the vast majority of the remaining 5% matched "the ____ world's largest" (e.g. "the Arab world's largest").

If you search `* world 's _jjt*`, you will be able to find numbers for other superlatives (since `_jjt*` matches superlative adjectives), all of which seemed consistent with what I found for "largest".

Comment: Nice answer, but this does not explain why we use the word "the" in such cases, though I will still give you an upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need the definite article before a superlative, it doesn't matter if it's preceded by a [possessive noun](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-possessive-nouns.html), see the online examples with "airline's" "university's", and "country's".

*airline's*

- *Bangkok was once again **the** airline's **busiest** route, with a total of 742,759 passengers flying to Thailand's capital city in 2013*
- *…operating flights twice a day from Kigali to Johannesburg, one of **the** airline's **busiest** route in Africa.*
- *Long Beach Airport at 5:15 p.m. and depart from McCarran International Airport at 6 p.m., will result in **the** fledgling airline's **busiest** route.*

*university's*

- *Years ago **the** university's **most noteworthy** offering was—surprise, surprise—its agricultural program*
- *Two hundred and forty-eight honorees were inducted into **the** university's **most prestigious** donor recognition society, representing more than ...*

*country's*

- *Rent prices are doing something unexpected in some of **the** country's **most expensive** cities.*
- *South Dublin **the** Country's **Most Expensive** Area.*
- *Cambodian premier Hun Sen on Monday opened **the** country's **largest** hydropower scheme, swatting aside dire warnings about the...*

There are few exceptions, when [determiners](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/determiners.htm) other than "the" are used to qualify possessive nouns, such as *a*, *this*, *that*, *my*, *our*, *their* etc.

**Exceptions**

- *Three hundred years later, it continues to attract **that** country's **best and brightest**. Hong Kong and Singapore have thrived by establishing themselves as...*
- *Because fuel is a major expense in the aviation world, officials say it is in **an** airline's **best interest** to seek an efficient streamlined fueling process to keep related costs as minimal as possible.*
- *... clearly needed, that **a** university's **most precious** asset is not its endowment but the reputation and effectiveness of its professors, and that professors do their ...*
- *As president of **my** university's **most popular** fraternity, I had a lot of social and philanthropic issues to attend to. I took this position very seriously and chose ...*
- *it is essential that we manage their consequences toward **this** university's **greatest** good.*
- ***Our*** fifth president's **greatest** legacy carries his name: The Monroe Doctrine.
- *"If we don’t contain **this** president’s **worst** foreign policy impulses on Europe and Russia, we could be living with the wreckage for generations."*
- *It has become one of **this** country's **most famous and fabulous** events*.
- *BBVA also announced that it was discussing a merger with Bancomer of Mexico to create **that country's largest** bank*

Comment: If you replace "the definite article" with "a determiner", you can remove all the exceptions you listed.

Comment: @Lawrence well that's the idea, I agree. Just illustrating how it works to the OP.